# JQuery vector using PHP

Tags: php, jquery

```
  $( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
    source: [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ]
  }); // this is the simple version. LOOK TO THE UPDATE!!!
```

This is my JQuery code.

Question: How can I create the vector of the programming laguages using PHP !?

**UPDATE:**

jquery

```
var keys = null; // HERE I NEED THE ARRAY, ANY ARRAY GENERATED USING PHP

$("#word").autocomplete({
    source: function(req, response) { 
    var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(req.term); 
    var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + re, "i" ); 
        response($.grep( keys, function(item){ 
            return matcher.test(item); }) );
     },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $('#word').val(ui.item);
    }
});
```

html

```
 <form method="POST" name="search" action="">
    <label for="autocomplete">Im looking for:</label>

    <input type="text" id="word" name="word" /> 
    <input type="hidden" id="word_id" name="word_id" />
 </form>
```

php

```
   for($i = 1; $i < $total_rows; ++$i) 
   {
      $sample_return[] = array("id"=>$i,"label"=>$ar1[$i],"value"=>$ar2[$i]);
   }
```

Comment: What exactly is a "vector" in this context ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to populate the autocomplete list using a PHP script loaded dynamically instead of a static list in JavaScript?

Comment: by vecotr I mean array, it's normal to call it like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can output any varaible from PHP into JavaScript (excluding resources) with [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json-encode).

In this case:

```
source: <?php echo json_encode(Array("c++","java"...)); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick example I put together, it shows what your really trying todo (eventully), its better to use ajax to query a "feeder file" that will serve as the autocomplete `source:`

Rather then render/echo **ALL** the values directly into the page:

```
<?php 
//Check request is from a ajax request
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === 'xmlhttprequest'){
    //check the term passed to this php from jquery autocomplete 
    if(!empty($_GET['term']) && strlen(trim($_GET['term'])) >= 2){
        //This is where you would query your db for the values using a LIKE%

        $sample_return = array(
        array('id'=>1,'label'=>"C++",'value'=>'c'),
        array('id'=>2,'label'=>"Java",'value'=>'Java'),
        array('id'=>3,'label'=>"PHP",'value'=>'php'),
        array('id'=>4,'label'=>"JavaScript",'value'=>'javascript'),
        array('id'=>5,'label'=>"ASP",'value'=>'asp'),
        array('id'=>6,'label'=>"Ruby",'value'=>'ruby'),
        );
        //boom
        die(json_encode($sample_return));
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
        source: "autocomplete.php",
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            alert('Do something with: ID:' + ui.item.id + ' NAME:' + ui.item.label+' VALUE:' + ui.item.value);
        }
    });
});
</script>

<form method="POST" name="search" action="">
  <label for="autocomplete">Im looking for:</label>
  <input type="text" id="autocomplete" name="search" size="50">
  <input type="button" class="button" value="Search"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Posted an update, because it did not solve the problam in general although it solved my question. (without update)

Answer (score 0):

You should `json_encode` it:

```
$langs = array( "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby");

echo json_encode($langs); // this will produce the desired output
```

But please, don't inject it into you js code, do like this instead:

```
<script type="application/json" id="langs">
   <?php echo json_encode($langs); ?>
</script>
```

---

```
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
  source: $.parseJSON($('#langs').text());
});
```

This way you decouple your JS code from the data source.