# autocomplete to enter return data into 3 fields when selected

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, json

Building a basic invoice page and I got the autocomplete working for my first input "item" and know that ajax can put the other two fields data into the input fields when I select and option. Not sure what has to be added to my code or where to go . Thanks

```
...
<input type="text" placeholder="Item #1" class="form-control auto" id="auto"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    //autocomplete
    $("#auto").autocomplete({
        source: "search1.php",
        minLength: 1
    });

});
</script>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Description" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-1">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Qty." class="form-control" id="qty"/>
</div>
<div class="col-md-1">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Tax" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Item Total" class="form-control"id="itemprice"/>
</div>
...
```

Here is my php file:

```
if (isset($_GET['term'])){
    $return_arr = array();

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_SERVER.";dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM items WHERE item LIKE :term');
        $stmt->execute(array('term' => '%'.$_GET['term'].'%'));

        while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $return_arr[] =  $row['item'];
            $return_arr[] =  $row['description'];
            $return_arr[] =  $row['price'];
        }

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    /* Toss back results as json encoded array. */
    echo json_encode($return_arr);
}
?>
```

Comment: Also check out for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16907246/jquery-vector-using-php/16907443#16907443

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this with the `select` callback for jQueries autocomplete.

```
 select: function(event, ui) {
        }
```

Assuming you return an array of data, just access each object within ui.item, then target the other input fields.

```
select: function(event, ui) {
            $("#secondInput").val(ui.item.id);
            $("#thirdInput").val(ui.item.value);
        }
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DLLVw/379/)

Answer (score 0):

do something like this :

```
$(document).on('change', '"#auto"', function(){
     var id = $(this).val();
     var $gty = $('#gty');
     var $itemPrice = $('#itemprice');
     $.ajax({
           url : '/myurl/info/' + id,
           type : 'POST',
           success : function(data){
              // fill inputs with data from ajax
              $qty.val(data.something);
              $itemprice.val(data.something);
           }
});
```

### edit

I don't think the other answer will work because jQUery ajax only returns an array of text / value .  It will not return the qty and item price , therefore you are going to need another ajax call to get the details on the specific item that the user selected from the dropdown

Comment: actually you can return custom items in jquery ajax. You just have to make sure that this item contains the standard 'name' and  'value' properties along with whatever you want to add.