# Not able to create auto suggest feature with dynamic data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-tags-input

I am using [this plugin](https://github.com/underovsky/jquery-tagsinput-revisited) to create combination feature of autocomplete and tag. 
My code  for input field and script related to it

```
<input id="form-tags-4" name="tags-4" type="text" value="">
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {

    $('#form-tags-4').tagsInput({
      'autocomplete': {

        source: [
          'apple',
          'banana',
          'orange',
          'pizza'
        ]
      } 
    });
  });
</script>
```

It is working fine with static data, however i want that in place of static data that is stored in source dynamic data of database should get stored.

currently my dynamic data is in $normal_skill whose format looks like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [normal_skill] => HTML
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [normal_skill] => CSS
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [normal_skill] => Javascript
        )
)
```

I tried to collect the data from normal_skill and put it inside an array like this

```
$items = array();
foreach($normal_skill as $n_skill) {
 $items[] = $n_skill->normal_skill;
}
```

And in place of source i called $items, after replacing source with $items, the autosuggest and tag feature stopped working.

For testing I printed $items, it was showing data but when replaced with source then there was no data. Console is also not showing any particular error.

Can anyone please tell how i can replace source with my data and i would want it also performs letter to letter search. eg:- if i type "h" then words starting with h should come in autosuggest, however right now all the words containing "h" are getting displayed

Comment: But it is not working is not a proper question. You have any error in console ? Alert items is this empty ? Try to debug your code.

Comment: @Shree Khanal I have edited my post. hope it can make a better clarity for you. Console has no error. If i print $items it shows data but when replaced with source then there is no data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try passing it to the javascript with `json_encode()`?

```
<input id="form-tags-4" name="tags-4" type="text" value="">
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {

    $('#form-tags-4').tagsInput({
      'autocomplete': {
        source: <?= json_encode($items) ?>
      } 
    });
  });
</script>
```

If its a remote source.

```
$items = array();
foreach($normal_skill as $n_skill) {
 $items[] = $n_skill->normal_skill;
}
exit(json_encode($items));
```

Then in your javascript, set it to the source file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {

    $('#form-tags-4').tagsInput({
      'autocomplete': {
        source: './tags.php'
      } 
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: it seems to work to fetch the data, but would also want it to perform letter to letter search. eg:- if i type "h" then words starting with "h" should come in dropdown, however right now all the words containing "h" are getting displayed

Comment: If you look at the console, your see it sends a `?term=` param with the value, filter or find by the value then respond with `[{"id":"","label":"HTML","value":"HTML"}]` json structure. Then use `ui.item.value` in your select callback. Its all in the docs for jQuery [autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote) as that lib is using it.

Comment: This is a better explanation, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48634888/display-unlisted-auto-complete-search-results-with-php/48638118#48638118

Comment: and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16907246/jquery-vector-using-php/16907443#16907443

Comment: the link that you gave, won't it call the api every time we type or do a search

Comment: No as its using [`minLength: 2`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-minLength) which will require at least 2 chars, also using [`delay`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-delay) is a good idea as a debounce so it only send once user finish typing.